# Proof of Friedrichs inequality in a domain with simple geometry

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Does exists a short, simple proof of the inequality

$ \|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leqslant C \|Du\| _{L^{2}(\Omega)} +  \|u\| _{L^2{(\partial{\Omega})}}  $ for $u\in H^{1}=W^{1,2}(\Omega) $

(Sobolev space with one weak derivative integrable in square),
 where $\Omega = \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\ 1<|x|<2 \}$?

(we do not assume, that the trace of $u$ vanishes).

Comment: This question is perhaps not suitable for this website. Anyway, a quick sketch for your specific case: using a density argument it suffices to prove for $C^\infty\cap H^1$. For smooth functions, use the fundamental theorem of calculus to get $$ | u(r,\theta) | \leq |u(1,\theta)| + \int_1^2 |\partial_r u(s,\theta)| ds \leq |u(1,\theta)| + \left(\int_1^2 | DU(s,\theta) |^2 ds\right)^2 $$ Now square, integrate over $r,\theta$, and you are done. 

Comment: Ack, the outer exponent in the far right of the displayed equation should be $1/2$, not $2$. 

Comment: Granted this question has an easy answer, but is this really worth the votes to close? 

Comment: By the way, the name is Friedrichs, not Friedrich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with a $C^1$ boundary and $u\in H^1(\Omega)$. We compute with $D_{x_1}=-i\partial_{x_1}$,
$$
2\Re\langle D_{x_1}u, i x_1u\rangle=-2\Re\int_\Omega x_1(\partial_{x_1}u)\ \overline{u} dx
=-\int_\Omega x_1\partial_1(\vert u\vert^2) dx=
-\int_\Omega \partial_1(x_1\vert u\vert^2) dx+
\int_\Omega \vert u\vert^2 dx,
$$
so that with Green's formula
$$
2\Re\langle D_{x_1}u, i x_1u\rangle=\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2
-\int_{\partial \Omega} x_1\vert u\vert^2\nu_1 d\sigma,
$$
and thus (Cauchy-Schwarz)
$
\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\le \sup_{x\in \partial \Omega}{\vert x_1\vert}
\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}^2 
+2\sup_{x\in \partial \Omega}{\vert x_1\vert}\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}
\Vert D_{x_1}u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}
$
implying
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\le \sup_{x\in \partial \Omega}{\vert x_1\vert}
\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}^2 
+\frac 12
\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2
+2
\sup_{x\in \partial \Omega}{\vert x_1\vert}^2
\Vert D_{x_1}u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2.
$$
The term $\frac 12\Vert u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$ in the rhs can be absorbed in the lhs, yielding the sought inequality. One could also fiddle with the choice of the multiplier $x_1$ and get better constants by replacing $x_1$ by another function and $\partial _1$ by another vector field.

Bazin.